# send ajax request without waiting answer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I want to make an ajax request to send some information and immediately after sending it (doesnt matter if I get an error/success) make a redirection (without waiting server response)

I was wondering if I do something like

```
$.ajax({
url:_myurl_,
timeout:500,
success:function(){document.location= _redirectUrl_},
error: function(){document.location= _redirectUrl_}
})
```

will work fine? Does adding a timeout wont cancel my request?

Comment: I think if you don't want to wait the success or error, you can use "beforeSend" ajax method. see documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: If you don't care about your request as completed or not, then ya you can use that but that's really a strange behaviour you are looking for...

Comment: @Fender I'm not sure how this would be handled. Doing a redirection should abort request (client side), so how this would be handled before sending it can give unexpected behaviour. I would say just the request won't be send at all

Comment: Yea, I dont care about the response of the server, but it have to be sended, that its my only condition.
@A.Wolff im wondering the same thing, not sure if the redirection will abort my request

Comment: A. Wolff, this is not a strange behavior at all. In my case, I need to do this for channeling log messages to the back end so that I can see them appearing in the same place. It could be used also for debugging purpose without exposing sensitive information in the console. And if the operation of sending it to the backend doesn't work, then it's not the end of the world.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I need to update a cart on every change of quantity to save reserve the stock of items in database in realtime (for online shop). So, I simply add a **timeout of 100ms** and **remove Success/Error callback**.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/update-cart',
  method: 'POST',
  data: {
    data: jQuery('#orderfrm').serializeArray()
  },
  timeout: 100
});
```

> Note : It doesn't matter if some requests didn't work, because when the order is saved, an update of the whole cart is sent with a callback.
> **If your query needs acknowledge, don't use that solution !**

Comment: timeout option works fine for me. thanks @Meloman

Answer (score 1):

Just do not implement any success handler.

So you could do ...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "/log-message"
});
```

And since it is asynchronous, it will be non blocking and any code following this statement will be executing without waiting from the response from the server.

Answer (score -2):

async: false
in async Mode process are not wait to complete other process

Comment: Never ever, ever set `async: false`