# Does http have to be a request/response protocol?

Tags: ajax, http, xmlhttprequest

I have to ask a plaintive question.  I know that http is normally request-response.  Can it be request-done?

We have a situation where we would like to send an ajax call off to one server, and then when that completes post a form to another server.  We can't send them both without coordinating them, because the post makes the browser navigate to another server, and we lose our context.

When I am currently doing is to do the first ajax call, and then in its callback, I'm doing document['order-form'].submit().  My boss pointed out that if the ajax call isn't completed for a while, the user will see his browser not make progress, even though it's still responsive.  He wanted me to put a reasonable timeout on the ajax call.

But really, the ajax call is a "nice but not necessary" thing.  My boss would be equally happy if we could send it and forget about it.

I'm having a lot of trouble formulating an appropriate query for Google.  "Use HTTP like UDP" doesn't work.  A lot of things don't work.  Time to ask a human.

Comment: As you said "My boss pointed out that if the ajax call isn't completed for a while, the user will see his browser not make progress, even though it's still responsive. " 

So why not add an UI element - say a progress bar or a spinner wheel which can show the user - the browser is still brewing up something while waiting for AJAX to return.  Also as far as I understand HTTP, since it is based on client - server paradigm is request -response based and is stateless (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-2.1)

Comment: A UI element expressing "I'm working" would certainly be an improvement.  I'd still rather send off a udp packet and forget it.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the ISO-OSI model of networking, HTTP is an application layer protocol and UDP is in the transport layer. HTTP typically uses TCP and rarely uses UDP. RTP (Realtime Transport Protocol) however uses UDP and is used for media streaming. Here is one more thing, UDP is not going to assure you a 100% transport, whereas TCP tries to (when packet loss is detected, TCP tries a re-transmission). So we expect drops in UDP. So when you say - fire and forget - What happens when your packet fails to reach?

So I guess you got confused between UDP and HTTP (and I am sorry if that' s not the case and there is something really with HTTP using UDP for web pages since I am not aware of it right now)

The best way, IMHO, to co-ordinate an asynchronous process like this is to have an AJAX call (with CORS enabled if required) like what you have written currently, coupled with good UI/UX frontends which intelligently shows progress/status to the end user.

Also - maybe we could tune up the process which makes the AJAX response slower..say a DB call which is supposed to return data can be tuned up a bit.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.  If the packet fails to reach, oh well.  We don't get that data.  //  This is what my friend and colleague said:  "Responses are not required unless you are making getRequests.  OPTIONS(Preflight), PUT or POST do not necessarily need response headers sent back to be of use."  Is he right?  I guess I would just not have an xhr.onload or xhr.ontimeout function.

Comment: I don't fully understand your colleague's statement, but what I gather is you are not worried what the AJAX call responds? So - then why not try a function block similar to the answer in this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35776803/send-ajax-request-without-waiting-answer

Comment: Or this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518363/possible-to-make-ajax-call-that-doesnt-return

Comment: Interesting.  I wonder if an event is emitted when a request has gone out entirely, but the response hasn't yet been received.  I don't think beforeSend is it.  "beforeSend, which is triggered before an Ajax request is started, . . ."

Comment: If I knew when the request had finished going out (could be a large file in the request body) I could go on to the next step, including navigating to another page.

Comment: Even looking here  --  https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/  --  I don't send an event that says "your xhr.send(blobOrFile); has completed."

Comment: Oh, wait, yes I do!    // Listen to the upload progress.
  var progressBar = document.querySelector('progress');
  xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
      progressBar.value = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
      progressBar.textContent = progressBar.value; // Fallback for unsupported browsers.
    }
  };  I wonder how many browsers can handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what Eric Bidelman says:

```
// Listen to the upload progress.
  var progressBar = document.querySelector('progress');
  xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
      progressBar.value = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
      progressBar.textContent = progressBar.value; // Fallback for unsupported browsers.
    }
  };
```

I think this has the germ of an answer.  1) We can find out when the request has entirely gone.  2) We can choose not to have handlers for the response.

As soon as you have been informed that the request has gone out, you can take your next step, including navigating to another page.

I'm not sure, however, how many browsers support `xhr.upload.onprogress`.

Answer (score 0):

If something is worth doing, surely it's worth knowing whether what you requested was done or not.  Otherwise how can you debug problems, or give any kind of good user experience?

A response is any kind of response, it need not carry a message body.  A simple 204 response could indicate that something succeeded, as opposed to a 403 or 401 which may require some more action.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured out the answer.  And it is extremely simple.  Good across all browsers.

Just add `xhr.timeout = 100;` to your ajax call.  If it takes the server a full second to respond, you don't care.  You already moved on at 1/10 second.

So in my case, I put `document['order-form'].submit()` in my timeout handler.  When the browser navigates away, I am assured that the request has finished going out.

Doesn't use any esoteric knowledge of protocols, or any recent innovations.